# what are the extra benefits of using Gradle listener? more benefits than TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, junit, testng

Recently I started using **Gradle**. I'm trying to make a test framework well structured. 
Based on the **Gradle** documents `TestListener` interface can support feedback from **JUnit** and **TestNG** tests.

**My question** :Is there any extra benefit in using this interface or I can just rely on **TestNG** listener?

I'm not sure if i'm missing some concept about it and I would appreciate your clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

The TestListener is really only useful if you are going to be building your own gradle test plugin. For your purposes I think you cannot go wrong by just using the standard Gradle Test task provided by the Java plugin. It provides its own test listeners and is very complete and extensible:
 https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html